# Sql whereNOTIn in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need your support to use whereNOTIn with laravel 5
to show all id in (times) table and they not in (booking)table and user_id

```
 $bookappoitm=DB::table('times')
    ->where('times.Dates_id',$id)
    ->whereNOTIn('id',function($query){
           $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
           ->where('users_id',Auth::user()->id)
           ->get();
        })->get();

The problem is
```

I can't use

```
->where()
```

with

```
->whereNOIn()
```

it gives me the result for the first `->where()`
and ignore

```
->whereNOIn()
```

Comment: may be in your nested query function data is returning as object, so it is not getting it, you should view us the error

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'times.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `times_id` from `bookappoitments` where `users_id` = 1 and `times`.`id` = bookappoitments.times_id)

Comment: $bookappoitm=DB::table('times')
        ->where('times.Dates_id',$id)
          ->whereNOTIn('id',function($query){
               $query->select('times_id')->from('bookappoitments')
               ->where('users_id',Auth::user()->id)
               ->where('times.id','bookappoitments.times_id')
               ->get();

            })

       ->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in right track but , first thing you need to know is wherenotin is used to compare your value with the array of values , so first you need is a array of value :
here is simple example to help you to understand a bit clearly so you can go through the problem :
by using query builder
DB::table('tablename')->select('fieldname')->whereNotIn('field1', [100,200])->get();
or
by using qlequent model

SomeModel::select('fieldname')->whereNotIn('field1', arraytmp)->get();

Comment: Thank you for your comment i got it :) but if i need to use where at first then use wherenotin what should i do, i select times by date id ; at first i select the date by dropdown list and then go to page to select time from this date ;i should use select all from times table where date id is..$id .. and then i make booking ; the time id should disapire from the dropdown list because of this i used wherenot in booking table :(